# make a function works after period of time without CronJob

Tags: php, laravel, cron

i have a function should work after 10 minutes of completed the previous function ,

i mean a have an e-commerce system with orders , what i need is to send notification after 10 minutes of order is set to complete,

i do not want to use CronJob, is there anyway to do this without CronJob

im working on Laravel

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend trying to avoid CronJobs for the matter. Is it really that necessary? There are some alternatives though, the only problem being that they are by far not more reliable or easy maintainable than CronJobs are.

Comment: Other alternatives for this, and without the `sleep` method of `php`, are either using jquery to make the requests or using http://socket.io with redis,

Answer (score -1):

you shold use event in laravel that set some listener after some action in your code
[Laravel Event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events)

Comment: events can't be used for this problem, since they are executed immediately without cron jobs, and Yazeed wants to achieve that without cron jobs